# Featured post in bootstrap 5 nav-pill

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Hi guys I am trying to create a featured post in bootstrap nav-pill, with categories.
When I click on category it shows 5 contents of the category in two separate divs and takes the first article as a featured article.

The problem is: First `$tab_content` is ok, which is first post as featured.

But second `$tab_content` displaying this `<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-5">` multiple times. so it doesn't go inline.

it should be like this : `<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-5"> 5 contents in here </div>`

**Edit** First tab_content which is first article goes in this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-7"></div>
```

Second tab_content which is displaying 5 articles goes in this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-5"></div>
```

Here are codes:

```
$categories =   array(
  array('tab_title'=>'catName-1'),
  array('tab_title'=>'catName-2'),
  array('tab_title'=>'catName-3'),
  array('tab_title'=>'catName-4')
);

$tab_menu = '';
$tab_content = '';
$i = 0;
  foreach($categories as $row){
    if($i == 0){
      $tab_menu .= '<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab-'.$row["catId"].'"> '.$row["catName"].' </a> </li>';
      $tab_content .= '<div class="tab-pane show active" id="#tab-'.$row["catId"].'">';
    } else {
      $tab_menu .= '<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab-'.$row["catId"].'">'.$row["catName"].'</a> </li>';
      $tab_content .= '<div class="tab-pane" id="tab-'.$row["catId"].'">';
    }
    

$articles = array(
  array('post_title'=>'some text for title'),
  array('catId'=>'40'),
  array('post_desc'=>'some text for post content'),
  array('catName'=>'category name'),
  array('post_seo_url'=>'sitecom/post_url'),
  array('post_image'=>'sitecom/images/image'),
);

      $first = true;
      foreach($articles as $sub_row){
      if ($first == true) { 
      if (!empty($row['post_video_url']) OR !empty($row['post_video_embed_code'])) { 
          $show = '<div class="w-100 mb-auto d-flex justify-content-end">
                  <div class="text-end ms-auto">
                  <div class="icon-md bg-white-soft bg-blur text-white rounded-circle" title="8.5 rating">8.5</div>
                  </div>
                  </div>';
      } else {
          $show = '<span class="card-featured" title="Featured post"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>';
      }
        $tab_content .= '
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-7">
        <div class="card card-overlay-bottom card-img-scale">
            <img class="card-img h-200" src="assets/fake_images/blog/4by3/06.jpg" alt="'.$sub_row['post_title'].'">
            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column p-3 p-sm-4">
              '.$show.'
                <div>
                  <a href="'.$sub_row['cat_seo_url'].'-'.$sub_row['catId'].'" class="badge bg-primary fs-6 mb-2"><i class="fas fa-circle me-2 small fw-bold"></i>'.$sub_row['catName'].'</a>
                </div>
              <div class="w-100 mt-auto">
                <h5 class="text-white"><a href="'.$sub_row['post_seo_url'].'-'.$sub_row['post_id'].'" class="btn-link text-reset stretched-link">'.$sub_row['post_title'].'</a></h5>
                <!-- Card info -->
                <ul class="nav nav-divider text-white-force align-items-center d-none d-sm-inline-block small">
                  <li class="nav-item position-relative">
                    <div class="nav-link">by <a href="'.seo_url($sub_row['username']).'-'.$sub_row['user_id'].'" class="stretched-link text-reset btn-link">'.$sub_row['username'].'</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">'.$sub_row['post_created_at'].'</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>';
        
        $first = false;
        } else {
        $tab_content .= '
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-5">
        <div class="card mb-3 ml-sm-3 mx-sm-3">
            <div class="row g-3">
              <div class="col-4">
                <img class="rounded" src="assets/fake_images/blog/4by3/thumb/01.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="col-8">
                <h5><a href="'.$sub_row['post_seo_url'].'-'.$sub_row['post_id'].'" class="btn-link stretched-link text-reset fw-bold">'.$sub_row['post_title'].'</a></h5>
                <div class="small mt-1">by '.$sub_row['username'].' - '.time_elapsed_string($sub_row['post_created_at']).'</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>';
          }
       }
      $tab_content .= '</div>';
      $i++;
  }
```

This is Usage :

```
<div class="row">
<?php require_once('modules/tabs.php'); ?>
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-line">
    <?php echo $tab_menu; ?>
   </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <?php echo $tab_content; ?>
  </div> 
</div>
```

thanks in advance for all helps.

Comment: Hi. Help us help. Could you remove your sql and replace it with an array of values? That way we could more easily try it locally. Also, I don't see any `col-lg-5`, am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy array added to question and in question, first article  **<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-7">Goes in here </div>** , and second 5 articles **<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-5">Goes in here</div>** I explained all in question. read edit part.

Comment: Your edit doesn't clarify anything. Neihter `<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-7">` nor `<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-5">` are contained in the code block you have shown us - so what are you even talking about here?

Comment: @CBroe they were in question at first, I removed. but added back now. I can do with ajax just dont wanna use ajax.

Comment: Move `<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-5">` from where it is right now, and add it to the end of `$tab_content` in the "first" block instead. And move the last `</div>` that is supposed to close this column element again, after the foreach loop body.

Comment: I tried that is well, then **<div class="tab-pane show active" id="#tab-40">** wraps all articles and tabs stops working.

Comment: Can you make a snippet or a pen in codepen?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer would help you.
I rearranged your categories and articles arrays since some data are not available on the array.
and also added if condition inside articles foreach loop to print relevant category tab data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$categories =   array(
  array('tab_title'=>'catName-1','catId'=>1,'catName'=>'catName-1'),
  array('tab_title'=>'catName-2','catId'=>2,'catName'=>'catName-2'),
  array('tab_title'=>'catName-3','catId'=>3,'catName'=>'catName-3'),
  array('tab_title'=>'catName-4','catId'=>4,'catName'=>'catName-4')
);

$tab_menu = '';
$tab_content = '';
$i = 0;

  foreach($categories as $row){
    if($i == 0){
      $tab_menu .= '<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab-'.$row["catId"].'"> '.$row["catName"].' </a> </li>';
      $tab_content .= '<div class="tab-pane show active" id="tab-'.$row["catId"].'">';
    } else {
      $tab_menu .= '<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab-'.$row["catId"].'">'.$row["catName"].'</a> </li>';
      $tab_content .= '<div class="tab-pane" id="tab-'.$row["catId"].'">';
    }
 
$articles = array(
  array(
  'post_title'=>'some text for title cat1',
  'post_id'=>'1',
  'catId'=>'1',
  'post_desc'=>'some text for post content',
  'catName'=>'category name',
  'post_seo_url'=>'sitecom/post_url',
  'post_image'=>'sitecom/images/image',
  'cat_seo_url'=> 'url',
  'username'=>'username',
  'user_id'=>'id',
  'post_created_at'=>date('Y-m-d')
  ),
  array(
  'post_title'=>'some text for title cat 2',
  'post_id'=>'1',
  'catId'=>'2',
  'post_desc'=>'some text for post content',
  'catName'=>'category name',
  'post_seo_url'=>'sitecom/post_url',
  'post_image'=>'sitecom/images/image',
  'cat_seo_url'=> 'url',
  'username'=>'username',
  'user_id'=>'id',
  'post_created_at'=>date('Y-m-d')
  ),
  array(
  'post_title'=>'some text for title cat3',
  'post_id'=>'1',
  'catId'=>'3',
  'post_desc'=>'some text for post content cat3',
  'catName'=>'category name',
  'post_seo_url'=>'sitecom/post_url',
  'post_image'=>'sitecom/images/image',
  'cat_seo_url'=> 'url',
  'username'=>'username',
  'user_id'=>'id',
  'post_created_at'=>date('Y-m-d')
  ),
  array(
  'post_title'=>'some text for title cat4',
  'post_id'=>'1',
  'catId'=>'4',
  'post_desc'=>'some text for post content cat4',
  'catName'=>'category name',
  'post_seo_url'=>'sitecom/post_url',
  'post_image'=>'sitecom/images/image',
  'cat_seo_url'=> 'url',
  'username'=>'username',
  'user_id'=>'id',
  'post_created_at'=>date('Y-m-d')
  ),
);

      $first = true;
      foreach($articles as $sub_row){

       if($sub_row['catId'] == $row['catId']){

                if ($first == true) { 
              
                      if (!empty($row['post_video_url']) OR !empty($row['post_video_embed_code'])) { 
                          $show = '<div class="w-100 mb-auto d-flex justify-content-end">
                                  <div class="text-end ms-auto">
                                  <div class="icon-md bg-white-soft bg-blur text-white rounded-circle" title="8.5 rating">8.5</div>
                                  </div>
                                  </div>';
                      } else {
                          $show = '<span class="card-featured" title="Featured post"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>';
                         
                      }
              
                    $tab_content .= '
                   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-7">
                    <div class="card card-overlay-bottom card-img-scale">
                        <img class="card-img h-200" src="assets/fake_images/blog/4by3/06.jpg" alt="'.$sub_row['post_title'].'">
                        <div class="">
                          '.$show.'
                            <div>
                              <a href="'.$sub_row['cat_seo_url'].'-'.$sub_row['catId'].'" class="badge bg-primary fs-6 mb-2"><i class="fas fa-circle me-2 small fw-bold"></i>'.$sub_row['catName'].'</a>
                            </div>
                          <div class="w-100 mt-auto">
                            <h5 class="text-white"><a href="'.$sub_row['post_seo_url'].'-'.$sub_row['post_id'].'" class="btn-link text-reset stretched-link">'.$sub_row['post_title'].'</a></h5>
                            <!-- Card info -->
                            <ul class="nav nav-divider text-white-force align-items-center d-none d-sm-inline-block small">
                              <li class="nav-item position-relative">
                                <div class="nav-link">by <a href="'.$sub_row['username'].'-'.$sub_row['user_id'].'" class="stretched-link text-reset btn-link">'.$sub_row['username'].'</a>
                                </div>
                              </li>
                              <li class="nav-item">'.$sub_row['post_created_at'].'</li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>';
                    
                    $first = false;
                
                } else {
                
                    $tab_content .= '
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-5">
                        <div class="card mb-3 ml-sm-3 mx-sm-3">
                            <div class="row g-3">
                              <div class="col-4">
                                <img class="rounded" src="assets/fake_images/blog/4by3/thumb/01.jpg" alt="">
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-8">
                                <h5><a href="'.$sub_row['post_seo_url'].'-'.$sub_row['post_id'].'" class="btn-link stretched-link text-reset fw-bold">'.$sub_row['post_title'].'</a></h5>
                                <div class="small mt-1">by '.$sub_row['username'].' - '.$sub_row['post_created_at'].'</div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>';
                  }
              }
       }
      $tab_content .= '</div>';
      $i++;

  }
?>
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-line">
    <?php echo $tab_menu; ?>
   </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <?php echo $tab_content; ?>
  </div> 




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This example shows only first (futured) post, and this example was in questions I have seen it before. I solved it with ajax.